# "Home-made" smoothly-disappear scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried this [jQuery plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) (Malihu scrollbar) to add amazing custom scrollbar in my projects and it works in simple web-sites.
However, I tired to use it in pretty complicated adaptive layout projects and it don't work. I don't understand Malihu scrollbar mechanism (the source code is pretty large), therefore don't know how to adapt if for my project.

So, I manage to create the scrollbar with mechanism that I can understand. The requirements is:

1. Thick
2. Semi-transparent
3. Smoothly disappeared when scrolling ended and appears again when scrolling started.
4. Do not affect in layout (by the language of graphics editors, the scrollbar is in the top layer and don't affect in other layers).
5. Cross-browser and cross-platform.

Solution for 1 and 2 is pretty simple, next is animation and independence in respect to layout. Please show me the most simple solution (OK to use jQuery).

I prepared the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztavkknd/) (currently correct scrollbar displays in Chrome only) with cleared 1 and 2 tasks to save your time.
(*There is no need to paste here the source code but the srackoverflow demands it for jsfiddle links*)

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(50,50,50,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Gurebu, I don't think your question really fits within the guidelines of StackOverflow. You're essentially asking for someone to do this work for you. You'd get a much better response from people if you made an attempt at your 5 goals, and then asked for help with that.

Comment: Have a look to this : https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html

Comment: Thank you for information source. I suppose Mac OS X Lion scrollbar will be exactly what I want. I will try to adapt it for my project from now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would personally recommend this well known plugin: [Prefect Scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar)

It is very customisable and easy to use.
The plugin is designed to work in modern browsers, and supports IE 10 and up.

It has support for appearance logic out-of-the-box, but I'm not sure it exactly fits your needs as it is. Look into it.

If you still need the scrollbar to disappear on the whole page when not scrolling, in order to achieve the your 3rd requirement, you can override the plugins css as you need & use the events the plugin supports, e.g.:

Alter the default appearance logic to make it invisible as a default:

```
.ps-container:hover>.ps-scrollbar-x-rail,
.ps-container:hover>.ps-scrollbar-y-rail { 
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And add this:

```
.is-scrolling .ps-scrollbar-x-rail,
.is-scrolling .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
    opacity: .6;
}
```

Then add a custom class (e.g. `is-scrolling`) to the same element you applied the plugin to, on firing the event of a scroll by the plugin that only then makes the scrollbar appear, e.g.:

```
$(document).on('ps-scroll-x ps-scroll-y', function () {
  $("body").addClass("is-scrolling");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The example on JSFiddle is really compact, so i think it will be really perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

I personally recommended good  plugin:  [**enscroll**](http://enscrollplugin.com/#documentation)

With the enscroll jQuery plugin, being able to write your own styles for those scrollbars is only a matter of a few lines of Javascript.

- The position and size of the scrollbars are automatically adjusted as
  you move the scrolling pane, resize the scrolling pane, or modify the
  scrolling pane's contents
- Support for touch events — full support for mobile devices, tablets
  and other touchscreen devices — now complete with scroll easing
- Optionally, keep the scrollbars hidden until the user hovers over the
  view pane
- Control how far the scrolling elements scrolls when using the mouse
  wheel or the arrow keys on the keyboard
- You control the class names of the scrollbar elements to allow any
  combination of scrollbar styles you need on the same page
- Preserve semantics — you don’t need to add any extra tags in your
  markup. Since enscroll adds these client-side, you can keep the
  initial DOM flatter

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollbox3">
<h1>New Scrolling Window</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a justo erat, volutpat hendrerit dolor. Sed urna nibh, dapibus at egestas non, vulputate ut quam. Morbi a erat tristique tellus varius venenatis. Aenean lacinia sem eget turpis fringilla commodo. Sed lorem nisi, viverra a interdum nec, varius eu enim. Donec ornare, nunc quis eleifend iaculis, nulla eros mollis tellus, quis faucibus risus odio non lectus. Maecenas ac velit non metus rhoncus commodo. Nunc ligula est, ultricies sed mattis sed, dapibus at arcu. Maecenas lacinia nisl ut sem bibendum ac condimentum purus facilisis. Curabitur ut nibh lobortis libero interdum vehicula vel quis nulla.</p>
<p>Suspendisse et massa urna. Donec eu lorem nec felis dapibus aliquam viverra in quam. Suspendisse ultrices, nisi ac venenatis porttitor, erat turpis dapibus augue, sed rutrum nunc ante sed enim. Aliquam et tempus mi. Nullam malesuada, nunc a eleifend pretium, justo lorem tempus justo, id adipiscing dolor ipsum sed velit. Maecenas odio massa, feugiat vel sodales ut, placerat at quam. Cras viverra diam vitae diam elementum vitae aliquet erat tincidunt. Quisque fringilla neque in lacus tempor cursus. Curabitur eget nulla et nisi dignissim tempor vel non risus. Mauris ac ipsum metus, a auctor massa. Nunc eros ante, ullamcorper a mollis nec, aliquam sed est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollbox3 {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 360px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}

.track3 {
    width: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    margin-right: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: background 250ms linear;
    transition: background 250ms linear;
}

.track3:hover,
.track3.dragging {
    background: #d9d9d9; /* Browsers without rgba support */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.handle3 {
    width: 7px;
    right: 0;
    background: #999;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: width 250ms;
    transition: width 250ms;
}

.track3:hover .handle3,
.track3.dragging .handle3 {
    width: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#scrollbox3').enscroll({
    showOnHover: true,
    verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
    verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
});
```

Here I make a small demo of it. [Have a look.](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Y5S/594/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Very good solution, really appreciate it; very sorry that I can't to give the prize to you, too.

Comment: Its OK  :). Keep coding. Your comment is prize for me. Thanks . just up vote it.